# How to set bandwidth on Mininet custom topology?

Tags: python, bandwidth, topology, mininet

I want to set bandwidth on Mininet custom topology.

The python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

class MyTopo( Topo ):
"Simple topology example."

    def __init__( self, **opts):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Initialize topology
        Topo.__init__( self, **opts )

        # Add hosts and switches
        h1 = self.addHost('h1')        
        h2 = self.addHost( 'h2' )

        s3 = self.addSwitch( 's3' )
        s1 = self.addSwitch( 's1' )
        s2 = self.addSwitch( 's2' )

        # Add links
        self.addLink(h1,s1,bw=10)
        self.addLink(h2,s3,bw=20)
        self.addLink(s3,s2,bw=10)
        self.addLink(s1,s3,bw=10)

topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

But it has error

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Caught exception. Cleaning up...
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bw'
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What can I do?
How to set bandwidth on Mininet custom topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `--link` argument. For example:
`sudo mn --topo tree,depth=2,fanout=5 --controller=remote,ip=10.0.0.1,port=6633 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13,  --link tc,bw=1,delay=10ms`

I'll update with an example soon.

Comment: But what if your custom topology has several hundred links, all with different bandwidth requirements? This would be silly to enter on the command line, is there a way to specify it in the python file?

Comment: @JohnScolaro Mininet cannot simulate such big network, You have to look for other solutions such as MiniNeXT.

Comment: Here bw=1 is equivalent to 1Mbps. How to set bw of a link to 1Gbps as it bw is taking values between 1-1000?

Comment: Please ask a new question

Answer (score 16):

You should add `cls=TCLink` on the `self.addLink(h1,s1,bw=10)`

so the code will be `self.addLink(h1,s1,cls=TCLink,bw=10)`

Add to the other `addLink` to make it work

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it uses Python like @kown 's example

Answer (score 4):

When starting Mininet, add an additional argument `--link=tc`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CLI command `mn` to run Mininet, add `--link=tc`.
If you are using a `run()` function in the python script to start Mininet, use

```
net = Mininet(topo = MyTopo(), link = TCLink)
net.start()
```

to start with Mininet with TC links for bandwidth specification to work.

Answer (score 0):

State the bandwidth and the delays in the python file, but while running the file, add

--link=tc

in the command line and it will work fine.